# OpenCV c++: Bad Argument (input arrays are different types) in absdiff

Tags: c++, opencv

I've been trying to use opencv to do speed estimation. The first step is to grayscale, blur and canny the images, and the second is to find the absolute difference between the two.
When finding the absolute difference, I get the following:

```
First scale conversion done:

OpenCV Error: Bad argument (when the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide 
functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified)
in arithm_op, file /opt/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 683.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
```

Heres me code:

```
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
Mat img,gray, blur, diff, tmp, canny, acc;
char first=0;

namedWindow("gray", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
namedWindow("frame", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);


VideoCapture cap("toy_plane_liftoff.avi");
if(!cap.isOpened())
{
    printf("Error 404: no video found\n");
    return 0;
}
else printf("Capture from file successfull!!\n");

double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);//bonus: frames per second counter
double frames= cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
double currentFrame = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
cout << "Frame per seconds : " << fps << "\n"<< "Total frames : " << frames << endl;

cap >>img;
acc = Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_32FC3);

for(;;) {
cap >>img;

if (!cap.grab())
{
    cout << "\n Cannot read the frame from video file" << endl;
    break;
}

Mat floating;
img.copyTo(floating);


cvtColor(floating, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
GaussianBlur(gray, blur, Size(3,3), 0, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT );
Canny(blur, canny, 25, 150, 3);

if(first==0)
{
 canny.copyTo(diff);
 canny.copyTo(tmp);
 canny.convertTo(acc,CV_32FC3);
 printf("\n" "First scale conversion done \n \n");
 first=1;
}
else accumulateWeighted(canny, acc, 5, noArray());

acc.copyTo(tmp);
acc.convertTo(tmp,CV_32FC3);
absdiff(canny, tmp, diff);

imshow("gray", blur);
imshow("frame", tmp); //show vid
moveWindow("gray", 30, 100);
moveWindow("frame", 700, 100);

if(waitKey(10) == 27 ||waitKey(10)=='q')
  {
        cout << "press esc to eject!" << endl;
        break;
  }
}
return 0;
}
```

I think it might be an issue of tmp not being defined the second time around.

Edit: I replaced

```
acc.copyTo(tmp);
acc.convertTo(tmp,CV_32FC3);
```

with

```
convertScaleAbs(acc,tmp,1,0);
```

and now everything is 'fine'

Comment: _"input arrays are different types"_ Yeah, it seems that `canny` is `CV_8UC1`, while `tmp` is `CV_32FC3`...  Also, you seems a lot confused on how to use `copyTo` and `convertTo`. Use a debugger and see what's going on, and if your matrices are as you expect.

Comment: @Miki You're damn right I'm confused, haha :(